# Default int main arguments in C/C++

Tags: c++, c

I was messing around with projects in C/C++ and I noticed this:

**C++**

```
#include <iostream.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

and

**C**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

So I've always sort of wondered about this, what exactly do those default arguments do in C/C++ under int main? I know that the application will still compile without them, but what purpose do they serve?

Comment: argc: argument count; argv: argument vector. They're the command line args to the program. And isn't it `char** argv` in C?

Comment: They provide access to the commandline arguments provided to the program.

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean

Comment: @mwerschy: Both `char*[]` and `char**` are valid.

Comment: @Kirilenko ah ok :) Didn't know C allowed that.

Comment: @mwerschy http://c-faq.com/aryptr/ Arrays are basically syntactic sugar for pointers (but they aren't always exactly the same, which is why you can sometimes use `sizeof(some_array)` to get the size of the array, but not always).

Comment: For what it's worth, the `c` and `c++` standards quotes: http://pastebin.com/erHUd4Gn

Comment: @BoBTFish "— argv[argc] shall be a null pointer." Huh, didn't know that. And it means you don't necessarily need `argc`, you can just iterate over `argv` until you hit the sentinel null... interesting.

Comment: `iostream.h` is not a standard header. Use `iostream`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They hold the arguments passed to the program on the command line. For example, if I have program `a.out` and I invoke it thusly:

```
$ ./a.out arg1 arg2
```

The contents of `argv` will be an array of strings containing

1. [0] `"a.out"` - The executable's file name is always the first element
2. [1] `"arg1"` - The other arguments
3. [2] `"arg2"` - that I passed

`argc` holds the number of elements in `argv` (as in C you need another variable to know how many elements there are in an array, when passed to a function).

You can try it yourself with this simple program:

---

**C++**

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++){
        std::cout << "Argument "<< i << " = " << argv[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

**C**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++){
        printf("Argument %i = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the argv ahs to be argv[] i think....as its an array

Comment: `char ** argv` is also allowed as an array may decay into a pointer in C. I believe `char * argv[]` is indeed preferred, but I'm used to this and it saves me 1 character and is slightly faster to type.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to accept arguments through commandline ,then you need to use the arguments in the main function .argc is the argument count and array of charecter pointers list the arguments.
refer this link http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson14.html

Answer (score 2):

Those are for command-line arguments. `argc` is the number of arguments, and the arguments are stored as an array of null-terminated strings (`argv`). Normally, a program with no command-line arguments passed in will still have one stored in `argv`; namely, the name used to execute the program (which won't always be there, depending on how the program is executed, but I can't remember what the circumstances are for that).

Answer (score 2):

*argc* and *argv* are how command line arguments are passed to main() in C and C++.

*argc* will be the number of strings pointed to by *argv*, this will usually be one more than the number of arguments you pass from terminal, as usually the first is the name of the program.